# pull distinct results from several tables

Tags: postgresql, count, union, distinct

I have an item table and item attribute tables, I'm looking for count of distinct item IDs that have had changes in either the item table or any of the attribute tables since a given date.

The IDs will be found in item.id, attribute1.item_id, attribute2.item_id, attribute3.item_id
The date will be found in item.updated_at, attribute1.updated_at, attribute2.updated_at, attribute3.updated_at

I tried this which gives me the unique IDs I'm looking for (53 total returned)

```
SELECT DISTINCT item.id
FROM postgres.item
WHERE item.updated_at >= (current_date - interval '1 week')
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT attribute1.item_id
FROM postgres.attribute1
WHERE attribute1.updated_at >= (current_date - interval '1 week')
```

But I need a count returned so I tired this,

```
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT item.id)
FROM postgres.item
WHERE item.updated_at >= (current_date - interval '1 week')
UNION
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT attribute1.item_id)
FROM postgres.attribute1
WHERE attribute1.updated_at >= (current_date - interval '1 week')
```

it gives me 4 and 52, those are the unique from each table but I need the 53 unique from the combined tables

Answer (score 1):

You can use using subquery as shown below

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT item.id
FROM postgres.item
WHERE item.updated_at >= (current_date - interval '1 week')
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT attribute1.item_id
FROM postgres.attribute1
WHERE attribute1.updated_at >= (current_date - interval '1 week')) tmo
```

Comment: this yields an error,   `ERROR:  subquery in FROM must have an alias
LINE 2: FROM (
             ^
HINT:  For example, FROM (SELECT ...) [AS] foo.
SQL state: 42601
Character: 22`  I will look into using SELECT AS

Answer (score 0):

This is what ended up working for me,

```
SELECT COUNT (*) 
FROM 
( 
SELECT item.id AS list
FROM postgres.item
WHERE item.updated_at >= (current_date - interval '1 week')
UNION
SELECT attribute1.item_id AS list
FROM postgres.attribute1
WHERE attribute1.updated_at >= (current_date - interval '1 week')
) AS list
```